# General state space

Tags: stochastic-processes, markov-process

Is there a clear definition for a "general state space" in the sense of Markov chains ? Is $\mathbb{N}$ a general state space because it is countably infinite?

Comment: What source are you quoting?  Please supply a reference or give a direct quotation and the context.

Comment: General state space Markov chains and
MCMC algorithms ∗
Gareth O. Roberts
Department of Mathematics and Statistics, Fylde College, Lancaster University, Lancaster,
LA1 4YF, England
e-mail: g.o.roberts@lancaster.ac.uk
Jeffrey S. Rosenthal †

Comment: [The abstract](http://arxiv.org/pdf/math/0404033) begins "This paper surveys various results about Markov chains on general (non-countable) state spaces." That seems to contradict your supposition.  Section 4 refers to "general (uncountable) state spaces." Those are the only instances of "general ... state space" that a search of the document turns up, so we have to take them as *definitions*. The rest of the paper exemplifies these definitions by focusing on Markov chains on $\mathbb{R}^d$ which is an *uncountable* set.

Comment: ok that is right butt look at example 3 on page 33. this is clearly a markov chain on $\mathbb{N}$. so they look at countable sets too.

Comment: Please pay attention to context. That chain is introduced as "Here is a simple example [of how] the chain may have unpredictable behaviour on a “null set” of $\pi$-measure $0$, and fail to converge there."  There is no implication that the example will involve a general state space.  In fact it would even have been legitimate to use a *finite* state space to make this point--except no such example is possible in such cases.